# Android WebView keyboard hides input field in fragment in android

Tags: android, android-webview, android-keypad

When I open WebPage into my `webView`,the input field is hidden by keyboard. How can I solve this problem? Please help.

```
web_view_proposel.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());
        web_view_proposel.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web_view_proposel.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        web_view_proposel.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        web_view_proposel.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        web_view_proposel.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        web_view_proposel.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
        web_view_proposel.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        web_view_proposel.loadUrl(Url);
        web_view_proposel.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        web_view_proposel.requestFocus();
        web_view_proposel.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (!v.hasFocus()) {
                            v.requestFocus();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: You could put the webView inside a scroll view, so the user can scroll and make the field visible again.

Comment: Thanks dude .. But it is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Siddhart add this to your manifest file, hope this will work in your activity entry

Comment: thanks Saurabh ..Its is work in Activity but Not work in Fragment .So Problem Still not solved

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940765/how-to-hide-the-soft-keyboard-from-inside-a-fragment

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All ..I get the Solution . if u set the height in drawer layout statically then keyboard hide textfeild problem occur but if u not set height statically then it will work prefectly..