# How to hide keyboard in fragment？

Tags: android, keyboard, fragment

I use this method to hide keyboard.

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
View v = getActivity().getWindow().peekDecorView();
if (null != v) {
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

But sometimes it is throwing NullPointerException, and the keyboard is n't hiding.

```
sync device with java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I have save the activity instance by override method onAttach,and use

```
activity.getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: duplicate issue 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940765/how-to-hide-the-soft-keyboard-from-inside-a-fragment

Comment: Have you tried using the onActivityCreated method?

Answer (score 0):

Try this bunch of code:

To show the soft keyboard:

```
public void showSoftKeyboard(View view){
if(view.requestFocus()){
    InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.showSoftInput(view,InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
}
```

You can force Android to hide the virtual keyboard using the `InputMethodManager`, calling `hideSoftInputFromWindow`, passing in the token of the window containing your edit field.

```
public void hideSoftKeyboard(View view){
  InputMethodManager imm =(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
  imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

From fragment or activity.

Answer (score 0):

to hide keyboard you can try :
note : to get getSystemService you need have activity.

```
public static void hideSoftKeyboard(Activity activity) {
    if (activity != null && activity.getWindow() != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (imm != null) {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

}
```