# Disable soft keyboard in android fragment(Make it never appear in the fragment)?

Tags: android, keyboard, tablet

I want to permanently disable the `soft-keyboard` from appearing in a `fragment` in `android`.

In my scenario there are three fragments that is integrated to a `viewpager` in an `activity`.

When i reach the second `fragment` which only contains a `spinner`. On `spinner` dropdown the `keyboard` appears.

Have **tried all solutions in stack overflow** yet nothing was successful.

Please **help me to permanently disable the `keyboard` from appearing in the Second `fragment`**

**Please keep in mind this is a tablet `application`**.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share what you tried?

Did this not work for you - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940765/how-to-hide-the-soft-keyboard-from-inside-a-fragment)

*Code*:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```